# jupyterhub on azure cannot set or locate jupyterhub_config.py

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04, jupyterhub

I am running the littlest jupyterhub per [this tutorial](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/azure.html). It's running fine every time, however I can't seem to locate the default `jupyterhub_config.py`.  Per [this documentation](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started/config-basics.html#:%7E:text=some%20common%20deployments-,Generate%20a%20default%20config%20file,in%20the%20current%20working%20directory.&text=This%20default%20jupyterhub_config.py%20file,variables%20and%20their%20default%20values.) it says that you can run a command line to generate the file, but I get the `command not found` error. However jupyter hub *is* working and fine.

I even tried to do this from the admin terminal (in the browser's jupyter notebook, not from the terminal). In this case I can run the `jupyterhub --generate-config` command and it will generate the file, but not in any place that is referenced by jupyter hub on boot. Editing that file makes no difference.

My question here is: How can I find the `jupyterhub_config.py` file that the application is running from. If I need to create one, where does it need to be in order to be read? and where is the command line that jupyterhub is launching from. The terminal leaves no clue (other than `top`) that it is running at all. My hope is to edit the experience of all of my users from a single config file.

Comment: Another possible solution is to reference a specific config file on boot, however I can't find the command line where Jupyterhub is running when the VM is started. If I could find the boot commands then perhaps I could modify I have no idea where I would find that file.

Comment: Yet another possible solution would be a command line that I could use to find the location of the config file that jupyter hub is using, or the folder that it is looking in. However I can't find such a command in the docs.